# Actionscript check custom object defined type (not actual type)

Tags: actionscript-3

Suppose I have a custom object variable that is set as null and I want to check it's type definition. How do I do it?

```
var a:MyObject = null;

// how do I check if a is MyObject?
//
// a is MyObject == false
// a instanceof MyObject == false
// getQualifiedClassName(a) <-- Exception
// typeof(a) == "object"
// describeType(a) <-- Exception
// a.constructor <-- Exception
// a.prototype <-- Exception
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Why would you need to check the definition anyways?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the way all of those examples in your question work.

They don't check the type that is associated with a variable - they check the type of the instance assigned to that variable. Here is a good example of why your examples don't make sense:

```
var prop:DisplayObject = new MovieClip();
trace(prop is MovieClip); // true
```

If this worked the way you thought it does, you would actually get `false` here.

All you're doing when you create a variable and give it a type is telling the compiler what type of instances it expects to see assigned to that property, and to throw an error if something that is not an instance of the expected type is assigned to it.

I don't think there is a way to determine what type a variable expects. Moreover, I think if you see a need to be checking what type a variable is expecting at runtime, then you're doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: How about doing a describeType( a ) and checking through factory.implementsInterface tags ? Just wondering if this would work.

Comment: @MartyWallace I know the examples I wrote check the instance but I wrote them for clarification. The reason I need this is because I'm writing a function for various models that gets an object and returns a "normalized" model instance where date strings are replaced with dates, time strings are replaced with timestamps, etc. Some of my models are initialized for example with null dates (var date:Date = null) but I still need to know that this property is a date (or expects a date) ...

Comment: @Ofir It seems like you're trying to write code to check things that you should know, rather than what Flash should know.